# What is the negation of the sentence "$\exists x_0 \in [0, C] :f(x_0) \in \bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} B_{\epsilon}(k\pi)$"?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, solution-verification

Let $f:[0, C]\to\mathbb{R}$. What is the negation of the sentence "$\exists x_0 \in [0, C] :f(x_0) \in \bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} B_{\epsilon}(k\pi)$"?

I guess it would be something like:
$$\forall x\in [0, C]: f(x) \in \left(\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} B_{\epsilon}(k\pi)\right)^c.$$

Could someone please tell me if it is correct?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is fine. The negation of "There exists a green cow" is "Every cow is some color other than green."

Comment: @TedShifrin Is that an ironic comment? Do you mean I am wrong?

Comment: No, no. I said it was fine. I'm just giving you a more intuitive way to think through it.

Comment: It is correct but sometimes it is more intuitive to write $\left(\bigcup A_\alpha\right)^\complement$ as $\bigcap A_\alpha^\complement.$

Comment: @TedShifrin okay, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step by step, take the negation:
$$
\neg\left(\exists x_0 \in [0, C] :f(x_0) \in \bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} B_{\epsilon}(k\pi)\right)
$$
then move the negation inside the existential quantifier by $\neg \exists x\in X : P(x) \iff \forall x \in X : \neg P(x)$ as
$$
\forall x_0 \in [0, C] : \neg \left( f(x_0) \in \bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} B_{\epsilon}(k\pi)\right)
$$
then move the negation into the set inclusion by observing $\neg (x \in X) \iff x \in X^\complement$:
$$
\forall x_0 \in [0, C] : f(x_0) \in \left(\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} B_{\epsilon}(k\pi)\right)^\complement
$$
that is, what you've got ;)

If you want to take it a step further, by De Morgan law on set union you also get
$$
\forall x_0 \in [0, C] : f(x_0) \in \bigcap_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} \left(B_{\epsilon}(k\pi)\right)^\complement
$$

hope this helps!